# Can't get the banana-rdf to work with scalajs

Tags: scala.js, banana-rdf

From my understanding I should be able to use the banana-rdf library in my scalajs code? I followed the instructions on the [website](https://github.com/banana-rdf/banana-rdf) and added the following to my build.sbt:

```
val banana = (name: String) => "org.w3" %% name % "0.8.4" excludeAll (ExclusionRule(organization = "org.scala-stm"))
```

and added the following to my common settings:

```
resolvers += "bblfish-snapshots" at "http://bblfish.net/work/repo/releases"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("banana", "banana-rdf", "banana-sesame").map(banana)
```

It all compiles fine until it gets to the point where it does the fast optimizing. Then I get the following error:

> Referring to non-existent class org.w3.banana.sesame.Sesame$

I tried changing Seasame for Plantain but got the same outcome.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the "%%" notation which is for a jvm module.

Changed it to "%%%" and it was able to find the correct library.

NOTE. I had to use Plantain as this is the only one currently compiled for scalajs